# how to use user sessions in dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, session, dialogflow-es, chatbot, actions-on-google

I want to use user sessions in my Dialogflow bot currently whats happening is when I save something in a variable in webhook it saves for all the users I don't want it like that I want different sessions for unique users

```
const axios = require('axios');
const express = require('express')
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send("Server Is Working.....")
})

app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
// get agent from request
  let agent = new WebhookClient({request: req, response: res})
// create intentMap for handle intent
   let intentMap = new Map();
// add intent map 2nd parameter pass function 
intentMap.set('weather',weatherIntent)
intentMap.set('sessiontest',sessiontest)
// now agent is handle request and pass intent map
agent.handleRequest(intentMap)
})


function sessiontest(agent){ 
    agent.add("session")  
    }


    function weatherIntent(agent){ 
const apiKey = "23756992e06787aa9225e9b361dfcd66"
const city = agent.parameters.city; 
const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}&units=imperial`
return axios.get(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response.data.main.temp); 
    agent.add("Temp in " + city +  " is " + response.data.main.temp)
    
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always execut
  });
  }


  app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log("Server is Running on port 3000")
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store session data within the session itself, with the parameters being passed in the JSON request and response. You can use [`conv.data`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.13.0/classes/_service_dialogflow_conv_.dialogflowconversation.html#data) to provide a key-value pair of variables you want saved.

```js
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.data.someProperty = 'someValue'
})
```

Comment: I have functions like this  function sessiontest(agent){ 
        agent.add("session")  
}  how can i do the same with this type of function?  @Nick Felker

Comment: I have pasted the code how can i convert into something like you shared by the way i want to use session variable on api function

Comment: You should use [contexts](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/src/contexts.js) to store data, ie. `agent.context.set('sample context name');` and `let context = agent.context.get('sample context name');`

Comment: @xjd Could you please confirm if the above solution is working fine

Comment: hey @ArokyaNehrayous I have used hashmaps I don't know its working or not I guess its should work he is pro i think